# ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hikaricp

We have made a rest spring boot spring data application on tomcat server . The application works in local environment . But when deployed on Production environment , the  application gives below exception after concurrent hits.

Exception:
ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30004ms.
javax.persistence.PersistenceException:

org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection

Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection

The application is deployed as war file in apache tomcat , connecting single data source to oracle

The configuration is follows :-
The application.properties is as follows:-

```
    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@xx.xx.xx.xx:1521/orcl
    spring.datasource.username=XXXX
    spring.datasource.password=XXXX
    spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
    spring.jpa.show-sql=true
    spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
    spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true
    spring.datasource.hikari.connection-test-query=SELECT 1 FROM DUAL


    spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout=60000
    spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=10
    spring.datasource.hikari.idleTimeout=60000
    spring.datasource.hikari.minimumIdle=5
    spring.datasource.hikari.idleTimeout=30000
    spring.datasource.hikari.poolName=SpringBootJPAHikariCP
    spring.datasource.hikari.maxLifetime=2000000
    spring.datasource.hikari.connectionTimeout=60000
logging.level.com.zaxxer = DEBUG
logging.level.com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig=DEBUG


logging.level.org.hibernate=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl=trace
logging.level.org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate = trace
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql=trace
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=INFO
logging.level.org.hibernate.type=TRACE
```

Also, the oracle database SP  File  is as follows

```
DB11G.__java_pool_size=16777216
DB11G.__large_pool_size=33554432
DB11G.__oracle_base='/data/app/oracle'#ORACLE_BASE set from environment
DB11G.__pga_aggregate_target=2382364672
DB11G.__sga_target=4294967296
DB11G.__shared_io_pool_size=0
DB11G.__shared_pool_size=2130706432
DB11G.__streams_pool_size=16777216
*.audit_file_dest='/data/app/oracle/admin/orcl/adump'
*.audit_trail='db'
*.compatible='11.2.0.4.0'
*.control_files='/data/app/oracle/oradata/orcl/cC  C"           F.  ontrol01.ctl','/data/app/oracle/fast_recovery_area/orcl/control02.ctl'
*.db_block_size=8192
*.db_domain=''
*.db_name='orcl'
*.db_recovery_file_dest='/data/app/oracle/fast_recovery_area'
*.db_recovery_file_dest_size=4385144832
*.diagnostic_dest='/data/app/oracle'
*.dispatchers='(PROTOCOL=TCP) (SERVICE=DB11GXDB)'
*.open_cursors=300
*.pga_aggregate_target=2367684608
*.processes=150
*.remote_login_passwordfile='EXCLUSIVE'
*.sga_target=4293918720
*.undo_tablespace='UNDOTBS1'
```

The database is deployed on 16 GB Ram
The spring boot pom.xml is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>war</packaging>   
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.mpcz.services.api</groupId>
    <artifactId>CommonServicePortal</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>CommonServicePortal</name>
    <description>Services</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>

    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/xerces/xercesImpl -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.xercesImpl</groupId>
    <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.0</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/xml-apis/xml-apis -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
    <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.01</version>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- For Working with Json Web Tokens (JWT) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- marked the embedded servlet container as provided -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- hot swapping, disable cache for template, enable live reload -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>6.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Optional, for bootstrap -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mpmvvcl.mpmk</groupId>
            <artifactId>Common-Domain</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.paytm</groupId>
            <artifactId>paytmchecksum</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.tcs</groupId>
            <artifactId>pgi</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mpmvvcl.mpmk</groupId>
            <artifactId>MPMK-Utilities</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-activemq</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-spring</artifactId>
            <version>5.13.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20180813</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>serviceportal</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <includeSystemScope>true</includeSystemScope>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The hikari logs as following :

```
2019-04-30 14:50:39:633 DEBUG HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Timeout failure stats (total=10, active=10, idle=0, waiting=2)
2019-04-30 14:50:39:508 DEBUG HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Timeout failure stats (total=10, active=10, idle=0, waiting=3)
2019-04-30 14:55:08:420 DEBUG SqlExceptionHelper - Unable to acquire JDBC Connection [n/a]
java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 298435ms.
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createTimeoutException(HikariPool.java:591)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:194)
```

Oracle Database statisics

```
RESOURCE_NAME                  CURRENT_UTILIZATION MAX_UTILIZATION LIMIT_VALUE
------------------------------ ------------------- --------------- ----------
processes                                       53             150        150
sessions                                        58             156        248
```

Please inspect the configuration and provide the solution,
It may be something connected with the server closing connections before HikariCP does but I'm not sure. Any comment on this would be appreciated.

Comment: max pool size is 10. That seems a little low for a production environment.

Comment: @Gimby I had tried the max pool size to 50 , 100 , but still get the exception after some time. How much should i specify

Comment: You should close the connection after the request ends.

Comment: @minus We are using JPA as ORM , so the connection is autoclosable

Comment: @Aaruhi you should specify around 20 more than will be used at the same time at the busiest moment of the day. The database itself also has to be configured to allow that many concurrent connections. This is more a game of measuring rather than guessing I'm afraid, you can't really be helped much to trace it down as long as you don't want this problem to be about code.

Comment: Try to set a leakDetectionThreshold (for example 10s) to check in the log if the connections are leaked by the application.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing a similar kind of issue in hibernate generated query for creating a table, copied the generated query from the log, which was giving the exception, and pasted it to MySQL editor and found out that, I need to change the table name used in my java class.
@Entity
@Table(name="order_TB"), earlier I was just using "order"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).